# Find duplicate values in xml document with C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm loading an XML document via

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(fullPath);
```

The XML File has something like (simplifying it):

```
<customers>
  <customer>
    <guid>
  <customer>
  <customer>
    <guid>
  <customer>
<customers>
```

But in the real doc theres many nested customers. How do I search for and find all the customer elements with guid children witth duplicate GUID values (the text inside the guid element).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to find duplicates:

```
var dublicates = XDocument.Parse(xml)
            .Descendants("customer")
            .GroupBy(g => (string)g.Attribute("guid"))
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(g => g.Key);
```